# Pythonic way of transforming Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set like ;

```
x1      NAN         
x2      NAN         
x3      NAN     
NAN     y1  
NAN     y2
```

Is there a way to reshape the pandas dataframe to below;
It will be like sql outer join I guess , so I can multiply values .

```
x1  y1      
x1  y2      
x2  y1      
x2  y2          
x3  y1      
x3  y2
```

EDIT:
Reason; I have to transform an Excel file (which I have no control), to this format , to feed another program (which I have no control)

```
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(
    '/inputfile.xlsx')
ncols = xl.book.sheet_by_index(0).ncols
df = xl.parse(0, converters={i: str for i in range(ncols)})

## Maybe this kind of Logic 
## But could it be Pythonic
# for index in range(len(df)):
#     if not pd.isnull(df.iloc[index][3]):
#         print(df.iloc[index][3])


writer = pd.ExcelWriter(
    'output.xlsx')  # engine='xlsxwriter'
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: What's the logic for that transformation?

Comment: It seems that outter join is what you are looking for (after splitting original dataframe), but your logic is indeed unclear

Comment: Logic :  I have to transform excel file to feed a legacy program .

Comment: @NeofytosBoufidis how can I do that , is there a snippet

Comment: I don't understand why my question downgraded 2 points , what is wrong with it ?

Comment: @atmosfer: There are many things wrong in your question, for starters how about explaining in question what logic should be their to to get from your input df to expected df. Can you give what you have tried do achieve this output. Having said that, I have not downvoted it!!

Comment: thanks @RahulAgarwal , I tried to format it your way but couldn't manage to make it

Comment: Can you explain the logic? It seems very unclear what you are trying to do

Comment: `Logic : I have to transform excel file to feed a legacy program`? this is not the logic. The logic we need is how to get from input df to output df

Comment: i tried to edit as you explain @RahulAgarwal , I hope i understand you right

Comment: This is not what I meant...in plain english if you need to explain how come in your output df there are no `NAN` columns? Why every row of `x1 c1` is repeated twice? What is the logic for all these things which are happening?

Comment: I have to distribute/multiply  y values (their first 2 column is NAN that it how I understand they are y ) to x values

Answer (score 0):

you can start with the following quick hack

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=df.values.reshape(-1))

for i in df1[0].str.replace('\d+','').unique():
    df1[i] = df1[0]
df1 = df1[df1[0].str.replace('\d+','').dropna().unique()]
for xx in df1.columns:
    df1[xx] = df1[xx].apply(lambda x:x if type(x)==str and x.startswith(df1[xx].name) else np.nan )

df1



        x   c   y   title
     0  x1  NaN NaN NaN
     1  NaN c1  NaN NaN
     2  x2  NaN NaN NaN
     3  NaN c2  y1  NaN
     4  x3  NaN y3  title1
     5  NaN c3  NaN title2
     6  NaN NaN NaN NaN
```